# Sort nested python dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

**How to sort nested python dictionary items by their sub-values and save that dictionary items in descending order**
**Describing dictionary_____**

Before sorted

```
    dict={
          "Bob": {"Buy": 25, "Sell": 33, "Quantity": 100}
          "Moli": {"Buy": 75, "Sell": 53, "Quantity": 300}
          "Annie": {"Buy": 74, "Sell": 83, "Quantity": 96}
          "Anna": "Buy": 55, "Sell": 83, "Quantity": 154}
         }
```

**I want to sort dictionary items in descending order by their sub- values(i.e: "Quantity") and the output should be like this:----**

After sorted

```
    dict={
          "Moli": {"Buy": 75, "Sell": 53, "Quantity": 300}
          "Anna": "Buy": 55, "Sell": 83, "Quantity": 154}
          "Bob": {"Buy": 25, "Sell": 33, "Quantity": 100}
          "Annie": {"Buy": 74, "Sell": 83, "Quantity": 96}
         }
```

Comment: You can't sort dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend extracting the sorted keys and then creating a new dictionary.

```
def sort_by_quantity(dic):
  keys = sorted(dic.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]['Quantity']) # list of sorted keys
  return dict((x, y) for x, y in keys) # convert tuple back to dict
```

Comment: From the example it looks like OP wants the order to be decreasing so I think you need to use `-x[1]['Quantity']` or add `reverse=True`. Also, I think you can just return `dict(sorted(dic.items(), key=lambda x: -x[1]['Quantity']))` straight up.

Comment: Note this will work for Python 3.6+ because it ensure insert order is preserved from this version.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
dictt={"Bob": {"Buy": 25, "Sell": 33, 
"Quantity": 100},"Moli": {"Buy": 75, "Sell": 53, 
"Quantity": 300},"Annie": {"Buy": 74, "Sell": 83, "Quantity": 96}, 
"Anna": {"Buy": 55, "Sell": 83, "Quantity": 154}
}
sdct = dictt.copy()
def func(d):
    `return sdct[d]['Quantity']
dct = sorted(dictt, key=func, reverse=True)
newDict = {i: dictt[i] for i in dct}
print(newDict)
```

Comment: Note this will work for Python 3.6+ because it ensure insert order is preserved from this version